# Getting a list of files that match a Windows Files Search Criteria in R

Tags: r

I'm just trying to get a list of R Markdown files I have on my computer. I thought this would be simple but it doesn't appear to be.

I'd like a list of all markdown files on the **whole** computer.

I tried:
Setting the working directory to the saved search

```
setwd("C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/.rmd.search-ms")
Error in setwd("C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/.rmd.search-ms") : 
  cannot change working directory
```

Code below resulted in empty lists:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rmd$")
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rmd$", ignore.case=TRUE)
list <- list.files("C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/.rmd.search-ms", pattern = NULL, full.names = FALSE)
```

This resulted in character(0)

```
Sys.glob(file.path("C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/.rmd.search-ms", "*.rmd"))
character(0)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you think that it might be related to the error message with `setwd` ?

Comment: perhaps but i do not know how to fix that either. :-/

Comment: Is **.rmd.search-ms** a folder ?

Comment: I looked at the properties. Type of File: Saved Search (.search-ms)

Ultimately all i'd like is a list of all .rmd files on my whole computer so perhaps this can be done through other methods

Comment: `files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rmd$", ignore.case=TRUE)` just resulted in a list of rmarkdown files on the working directory, not the whole computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all users starting at the `/Users/*` path on windows OS...

Process is:

- Get all file paths from the home `/Users/` paths
- Recursively loop through each resolved file path
- Find all RMD file types
- return the file paths that match

  ### Edit for library clarification.....

  ```
  library(magrittr)
  Map(list.files, Sys.glob("/Users/*"), 
      full.names = TRUE, 
      no.. = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, 
      pattern = "\\.rmd$", 
      ignore.case = TRUE,
      USE.NAMES = FALSE
  ) %>% unlist()
  ```

Comment: thank you but this didn't work because of an error probably on my end. can you explain what i need to place   `Sys.glob("/Users/*")` do I place `"C:/Users/PUTMYUSERNAMEHERE"` in there?

Comment: `C:/Users/PUTMYUSERNAMEHERE/*`

Comment: ok thank you. I got the following errors though `Map(list.files, Sys.glob(C:/Users/PUTMYUSERNAMEHERE*), 
Error: unexpected '/' in "Map(list.files, Sys.glob(C:/"
    full.names = TRUE, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "    full.names = TRUE,"
     no.. = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "    no.. = TRUE,"
    pattern = "\\.rmd$", 
Error: unexpected ',' in "    pattern = "\\.rmd$","
    ignore.case = TRUE,
Error: unexpected ',' in "    ignore.case = TRUE,"
    USE.NAMES = FALSE
) %>% unlist()
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"`

Comment: `Map(list.files, Sys.glob("C:/Users/PUTMYUSERNAMEHERE/*"), 
+     full.names = TRUE, 
+     no.. = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, 
+     pattern = "\\.rmd$", 
+     ignore.case = TRUE,
+     USE.NAMES = FALSE
+ ) %>% unlist()`  resulted in `Error in Map(list.files, Sys.glob("C:/Users/PUTMYUSERNAMEHERE/*"), full.names = TRUE,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"`